# Java RestAssured: Using Json Variable

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am using Java Restassured with GraphQL. We have a Query and Variable.
Our variable is slightly different as it is JSON format.

What is the syntax to utilize Variable JSON Format? My Variable is Not a Java class, but rather json. Should I just convert my Json into an Object, and send into query? What should I put in body method?

**RestAssured**

```
given().
    body(??).
    when().
    post("https://www.test.com").
    then().
    assertThat().
    statusCode(200);
```

**Query:**

```
mutation GetData(  
    $input: testPerson!) 
     {    
        personAccountInfo 
            {
```

**Variable:**

```
{
  "input": {
    "person": {
      "name": "Joe",
      "age": "50"
    },
    "address": {
      "street": "Maple St",
      "zipCode": "90210",
      
  }
}
```